# Room - SQLiteLog: (1) too many SQL variables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have a table of about 10,000 records.

Example, I have the following entity:

```
@Entity(tableName="cupcakes")
public class CupcakeEntity {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  @ColumnName(name = "id")
  long id;

  @ColumnName(name = "name")
  String name;

  @ColumnName(name = "parent_id")
  Long parentId;
}
```

Then, I self-join `CupcakeEntity` with this class:

```
public class CupcakeModel {

  @Embedded
  CupcakeEntity cupcake;

  @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "parent_id")
  List<CupcakeEntity> parent;
}
```

When I fetch `CupcakeModel` with an SQL Statement:

`SELECT * FROM cupcakes WHERE name LIKE '%' || :keyword || '%'`

The query will throw an exception of:

```
too many SQL variables (code 1): , while compiling: 
SELECT id,name,parent_id FROM `cupcakes` WHERE parent_id IN
(?,?,?,?...............................
```

I've looked into the generated code of Room and found out that it's looping for all entities.

Is there any other workaround for this other than creating my own JOIN statements?

Comment: You could try using `LIMIT` or something to constrain how many `CupcakeModel` instances you get. My interpretation of your error is that your query is returning lots of cupcakes, and Room is trying to get all the parents in one query. Ideally, Room would handle that better (loading the parents in batches) -- if you can easily create a reproducible test case, you might consider filing a feature request.

Comment: I'll try using `LIMIT`

Comment: `LIMIT` does the trick! Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll just leave this answer here in case somebody bumps into this issue.

As suggested by @CommonsWare, I added a `LIMIT` to my query which now looks like:

`SELECT * FROM cupcakes WHERE name LIKE '%' || :keyword || '%' LIMIT 500`

Credits to @CommonsWare for this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

used below query for like ..

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%' || :arg0 || '%'")
List<MyTable> getData(String arg0);
```

Comment: It's the same query that I did, except that I'm using a different model for the result since I'm using `@Embedded` and `@Relation`

Comment: @AndroidTeam, this is not an answer to the question. Please read the question carefully and answer responsively.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have 1178 records to delete and my solution is

```
val chunkSize = 500 // Maximum number of IDs per delete operation
val mPharId = // Your list of IDs to delete

val chunks = mPharId.chunked(chunkSize)
for (chunk in chunks) {
    dao.delCustomerByIds(chunk)
}
```